# Import Intellij project folder to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, import, share

I have to work on someone else's android application project but he works on **Intellij**. When I asked him for the source code he shared **the whole project folder** with me and told me to set up certain modules and libraries on my computer.

However

1. I cannot simply import the project to Android Studio because **"There are unrecoverable errors"**
2. I cannot open the project in Intellij I downloaded because the code opens up with full of errors (the most basic **symbols are not resolved**) and it says the **project SDK is not defined** and no matter what I do I cannot correct this
3. I tried simply starting a **new project** on **Android Studio** and **replacing** all the java, xml files and resources and libraries. It sort of worked, but there are some bugs that weren't there in the original project.

So, how do I "take" this project from the previous programmer? I can ask him to give more/different folders if necessary but I can't ask for his computer :D

P.S. the bug I was talking about is some glitch of the textbox. Like instead of staying in the center it goes up and downs for a couple of times and then stays in the wrong location.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Android studio is intellij

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Aren't they sort of different versions of the same software?

Comment: they wont affect that much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume by Inteliij project you refer the pre-Gradle project structure.

You can try several things but two come in my mind:

- `IDEA` is fully Android Studio-compatible, all you need is enable its `Android` plugin. Then you can try to `Import Project` from `IDEA` rather `Android Studio`
- if above does not work, you will need some manual changes in the proj structure

  - create a dummy Gradle project form `Android Studio` which has same package structure
  - move your `src` folders from original project into `/src/main/java` new project
  - override `AndroidManifest.xml` at `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. You will need to clean some parts in your manifest after that though
  - move `/res` folder from original to `/src/main/res`

Clean and try again.